# Spring Integration: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'

Tags: java, spring

Let me preface this by saying that I had this code working, but I did something and can't get it to work no matter what.

I'm writing a small Spring Integration application that exclusively uses Java Config.

Here's the logs when I get the error:

```
pool-3-thread-2 || INFO  o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer || Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'null' channel
pool-3-thread-2 || INFO  o.s.i.c.DirectChannel || Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s).
pool-3-thread-2 || INFO  o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer || started org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer@282097a6
pool-3-thread-2 || DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory || Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationGlobalProperties'
pool-3-thread-2 || DEBUG o.s.i.c.DirectChannel || preSend on channel 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel@6d16efa2', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[244], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@36ebee89, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@36ebee89, ip_tcp_remotePort=42432, ip_connectionId=localhost6.localdomain6:42432:8080:c93ee59a-17e3-4c19-98a5-6bb374652181, ip_localInetAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, ip_address=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, id=54cbd13c-bb4b-0986-8bc1-93d436884be7, ip_hostname=localhost6.localdomain6, timestamp=1460066984381}]
pool-3-thread-2 || DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.TcpInboundGateway || failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
pool-3-thread-2 || ERROR o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection || Exception sending message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[244], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=42432, ip_connectionId=localhost6.localdomain6:42432:8080:c93ee59a-17e3-4c19-98a5-6bb374652181, ip_localInetAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, ip_address=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, id=972d1c96-238a-2598-b488-50c00710f12b, ip_hostname=localhost6.localdomain6, timestamp=1460066984373}]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
        at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:422)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:390)
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:119)
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorkadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:153)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

The most confusing part is the unknown.channel.name part. I have no clue where this is coming from, and it isn't mentioned once in the logs before the error occurs.

There are two classes that utilize Spring Integration:

**AppConfig.java**

```
package com.acme.project.spring;


@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = "classpath:/application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;


    @Bean(name = "inputChannel")
    public static MessageChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "handlerChannel")
    public static MessageChannel handlerChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "replyChannel")
    public static MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "handlerChannel")
    public interface Gateway {
        String send(String request);
    }

    @Bean(name = "inputGateway")
    public TcpInboundGateway inputGateway(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        LOGGER.info("get inputGateway");
        TcpInboundGateway gw = new TcpInboundGateway();
        gw.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        gw.setRequestChannel(inputChannel());
        gw.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());
        return gw;
    }


    @Bean(name = "serverFactory")
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverFactory() {
        Integer port = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("portNumber"));
        AbstractServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port);
        factory.setSerializer(serializer());
        factory.setDeserializer(deserializer());
        return factory;
    }


    @Transformer(inputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public String convertFromMyObject(MyObject obj) {
        ... 
        return obj.toString();
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
    public MyObject convertToMyObject(byte[] bytes) {
       ...
       return new MyObject(bytes);
    }

    @Bean(name="serializer")
    public Serializer serializer() {
        return new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "deserializer")
    public Deserializer deserializer() {
        return new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "a")
    public A getA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean(name = "b")
    public B getB() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

========

**Handler.java**

```
package com.acme.project.spring;

@MessageEndpoint
public class Handler {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private B b;


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "handlerChannel", outputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public MyObject handle(MyObject request) {
            MyObject response = new MyObject();
            ...
            return response;
    }


    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.acme.project.spring");
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

I think it's pretty straightforward. I stripped out all the non-Spring parts -- notably business logic and such -- and simplified some class names (A/B). Basically, I have 3 channels: inputChannel, replyChannel, and handlerChannel. The flow, as I understand it when it was working is:

serverFactory -> serializer -> inputChannel -> transformer(convertToMyObject) -> handlerChannel -> ServiceActivator(Handler#handle) -> transformer(convertFromMyObject) -> replyChannel -> back to the client

Any help to determine what 'unknown.channel.name' is, what's causing to exist now, and what's going wrong with the dispatcher would be tremendously helpful. I feel like it should be relatively simple -- perhaps a messed up annotation -- but I just can't seem to spot it.

Thanks,

Comment: Its been awhile since I have done Spring Integeration, and I have only done it with XML config.  However I couldn't sketch out your flow.  Just as a tip, if you put your service activator and transforms etc into a chain you don't have to wire channels up between them, Spring will do that for you.